# How does Emacs manage Italics and Bold?

Tags: fonts

I use TrueType fonts with Emacs under X.

There are specific Italic and Bold files for most fonts.

All of them are recognized by font config and therefore by emacs.

How does Emacs uses bold and italic? Does it use the specific font that is provided or does it modify the regular font to make it italic or bold?

Comment: I believe Emacs will not try to create bold or oblique font variants "by hand". For example I use Terminus by default, and I know in some contexts Emacs wants to use an oblique font, such as for some headers in Message mode. But if I don't install the separate package with the Terminus oblique font, Emacs just shows the regular Terminus.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I still have Italics even if the font I'm using does not have any

Comment: By the way, I know the Emacs interface to fontconfig to be buggy. At the very least Emacs seems to ignore `<alias>` elements, unlike other programs such as rxvt. So beware, you may have to specify the _exact_ name of the font you want Emacs to use.

Comment: What is happening to me is that /italics/ are not shown like italics, but as underlined.

Comment: Fontconfig can synthesize bold and italic variants of fonts if it's configured to do so, other programs like Emacs can reuse that effort.

Comment: Excellent! I will investigate!